# $http.post in angularJS goes in error in without debugging mode only.in debugging mode its works fine.why?

Tags: angularjs, http-post

here is my javascript code

```
 $scope.addUser = function () {
                debugger;
                url = baseURL + "AddUser";
                $scope.objUser = [];
                $scope.objUser.push( {
                    "ID": '0',
                    "UserName": $scope.txtUserName,
                    "Password": $scope.txtPassword,
                    "Role":"Non-Admin"
                });

                $http.post(url,$scope.objUser[0])
                    .success(function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        alert("S");
                        window.location = "../View/Login.html";
                    }).error(function () {
                        debugger;
                        alert("e");

                    });
            }
```

here is my server method code

```
[HttpPost]
        public int AddUser(UserModel user)
        {
            //_entity.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            tblUser objUser = new tblUser();
            objUser.UserName = user.UserName;
            objUser.Password = user.Password;
            objUser.Role = user.Role;
            _entity.tblUsers.Add(objUser);
            _entity.SaveChanges();
               return objUser.ID;
     }
```

Comment: you shoud try it by adding a timeout

Comment: Did you check your server method, Is it always returning success

Comment: when I run project without debugger in browser it shows alert message i wrote in error of ajax.and after that it throws "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed".

Comment: it dont go in server method even i put debugger there also still

Comment: can you post your server method also

Comment: This could be many reasons but verify your base url and the port used. Also it could be that other program is getting your request. In my case it was skype.

Comment: URL and port are correct.and i dont have even skype or any other program installed in my system except VS and sql.

Comment: @tarzanbappa : i have added my server method code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promises to get the response. this can be inside into a service and call it whenever you want to use it.

```
this.addUser = function (obj) {
        var datosRecu = null;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var uri = baseUrl + 'addUser';
        $http({
            url: uri,
            method: 'post',
            data: angular.toJson(obj)
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            datosRecu = response;
            deferred.resolve(datosRecu);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            datosRecu = response;
            deferred.resolve(datosRecu);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Also `.error` and `.success` are deprecated.

PD: the parameter `data:` inside the `$http` correspond to the body. if you want to send parameters you should use `params:{}`

**EDIT:** 
Here i leave you a link how promises work. [Angular promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
Basically this helps to process data asynchronously

the example above can be used inside a service like this

```
myApp.service('myService', function($q, $http){

// here your services....

});
```

the service can be injected inside to any controller to provide the data that what you want, inside of your functions

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, myService){

  $scope.list = function(){
      $promise = myService.getAll(); // this will be the name of your function inside your servive
      $promise.then(function(data){
         console.log(data); //here you can se your promise with data like status and messages from the server.
      });
  };

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i think you are right.promises can be used here.but i am new to angularJS so i cant understand its code.can you give any link to understand promises in better way.?